# Gvim - YCM - show errors in balloons

Tags: vim, syntastic, popup-balloons

I was wondering if there is a way to show code errors in balloons like [Syntastic](https://github.com/millermedeiros/syntastic) when mouse hover on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way, the one Syntastic is using already: "Balloon Evaluation" (read `:h balloon-eval`). You can basically set a `balloonexpr` which defines the text to show in the balloon. If you want to show the balloons by only hovering the mouse regardless of where the cursor is, that is not supported by VIM at the moment. To be honest, that sounds like a very useful idea for a popup menu on right-click (see `:h mousemodel`).

Comment: how exactly should I do that ??

Comment: Have you read the help page? It says exactly how to achieve what you want.